# How can I use jquery slide toggle with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the `<p class="hidetext">` to be hidden and when click on `<div class="post-more">See more</div>` Will show the `<p class="hidetext">`

```
<div class="center">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="posts">
            <div class="post">
                <div class="post-img"><a href="#"><img src="img/post-img/1.png" width="100%" height="100%"  alt=""/></a></div>
                <div class="post-title">
                    <h1>BLA BLA BLA</h1>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>       

                <div class="post-text">
                    <p>
                        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here 
                        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here 
                        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here ...
                    </p>
                    <p class="hidetext">
                        Text hide  Text hide  Text hide  Text hide  Text hide  
                    </p>      
                </div>

                <div class="post-more">See more</div>
            </div><!-- one post  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you already try?? We're not here to do write your code…

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.post-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.post').find('p.hidetext').toggle();
    $(this).text( ($(this).text() == 'See more') ? 'See less':'See more' )
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lp5NF/3)**